# Org mode carry over indentation to next line

Tags: emacs, org-mode

It seems in this scenario:

`*** Point 1|`

If I hit enter

`*** Point 1
|`

the cursor is placed on the first column of the next line. How do I make it such that when I hit enter the cursor is placed thus:

`*** Point 1
*** |`

Comment: It's [M-Enter] :)

Comment: @rsm Hey thanks! M-Enter worked for me :D